# What is Window Message coded 641?

Tags: winapi

Not sure what this code 641 indicates. Does anybody know how to reverse look up meaning of this code?

--- EDIT ---

I also looked up in header file and notice there is WM_IME_SETCONTEXT = 641, but not sure what it is to do with my application.

I have a CListCtrl in GUI, and draw a CEdit control over its cell when the cell is double-clicked. When CEdit control in focus, I press 'ESC', CEdit control focus killed, but CListCtrl columns and rows disappear entirely after it receives this message. Maybe I missed some other details.

--- ADDITION ---

What I have done as a solution is to handle 'ESC' key in my edit control's OnKeyDown() handler, simply hide edit control window, thus no further message sent to parent control. I guess 'ESC' key must cause some window invalidation like message. But I don't know why it propagates to parent.

Answer (score 3):

It's [WM_IME_SETCONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374142%28VS.85%29.aspx). I don't know of a good way to look these up except for grepping the SDK headers for the number or hex number; from WinUser.h:

```
#define WM_IME_SETCONTEXT               0x0281
```

This doesn't always work for Windows enums as they can be defined as (OTHER_CONSTANT + 1) etc. Thankfully the worst set of these, the error message codes, have a lookup util [err.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/06/17/8611734.aspx) in the Platform SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to get messages you don't recognize.  The correct way to handle them is by forwarding to `DefWindowProc`.